# How to close angular2-multiselect-dropdown on clicking the data from the dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am new to angular and I was trying to access `angular2-multiselect-dropdown` for single selection and display the selected data. Here, I want the dropdown to close/hide on click of selecting the data. Please check https://stackblitz.com/edit/r7-angular2-multislect

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to create instance of `AngularMultiSelect` class in your component using `Viewchild` and then call it's `closeDropdown()` method.

Steps:

1. Add `#dropdownRef` in template

   ```
   <angular2-multiselect [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings" (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)" #dropdownRef> </angular2-multiselect>
   ```
2. Do the following in your TS file:

   ```
   import { AngularMultiSelect } from 'angular2-multiselect-dropdown';

   @ViewChild('dropdownRef',{static:false}) dropdownRef: AngularMultiSelect;

   onItemSelect(item: any) {
      console.log(item);
      this.dropdownRef.closeDropdown()
   }
   ```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/r7-angular2-multislect-cwpxj8?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Hi !
The text that should occur is "Fruits" . The text that is occuring on the dropdown is "Select". How do we change it ?

Comment: I think this is an issue with the library

Answer (score 1):

Use `@ViewChild` to access to the dropdown like this:

```
@ViewChild(AngularMultiSelect, {static: false}) dDown: AngularMultiSelect;
```

now you can close the dropdown whenever you want:

```
this.dDown.closeDropdown()
```